# Sending a broadcast in Android will automatically launch app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I am working on an android project in which a service needs to send a *broadcast* that contains data (lets say a `string`) to one or more *activities* that are not part of the same app, they are different apps.

If i send a broadcast that contains the data in an `intent`, will the applications receiving the broad cast launch automatically, or will they receive only when the user launches the activity?

What I personally would need is that a *broadcast* with the data be sent and then only when the user launches the app will it go and fetch the `string` data from the `intent`.

Comment: Did you write the other apps?

Comment: Yes I picture that I will write the other apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, if you send a broadcast intent, the  [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) (registered your intent) will receive the intent immediately.

However, to receive your broadcast , the applications that you want to receive your broadcast should have a Boradcast Receiver 'registered' for your intent ( like declared in the android_manifest.xml with proper action mapping for your intent inside  tag )

Please note that a broadcast will never create a Activity/launch a Activity. They are rather received by "Broadcast Receivers" which is another type

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know. I am knew at this and I need to learn quickly. Thanks once again for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can let the service write the String to a `SharedPreference`, and send a broadcast after that. If the activity is already opened, it can read the string directly. If the user opens the activity later on, it can check if there is anything in the `SharedPreference`, and read it (and then clear it afterwards, so it only reads it once).